# Is it correct to say "there be..."?

Tags: verbs, sentence, literature

I'm currently reading Tolkien's *The Lord of the Rings*. One sentence says:

> [...] where there be mountains of gold, they say.

English is not my mother tongue, but I've found the same expression somewhere else, probably in song lyrics as well. I would like to know if it is correct to use (apart from literature context) and what it means and how it is different from "where there are mountains of gold". Thank you!

Comment: The language in LOTR is consciously archaic. Nobody talks that way any more. That particular construction is a hypothetical use of _be_ (hypothetical because of the _they say_ at the end), which some might call a 'subjunctive'; it has the kind of meaning that real subjunctive verbs often have in languages with subjunctive mood inflection.

Comment: In some West Country dialects (i.e. South West England), "be" is used for "is" (and "am", "are") even today. But not in any standard varieties.

Comment: I cannot accept that "nobody talks that way any more". There are plenty of people of erudition who would deliberately employ such language for its elegance - in the same way people readily employ Shakespearian dialogue in order to get their point across. And long may it continue, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "there be" is from the past.  And nowadays only used when imitating the past.  Searching "there be" in Shakespeare's plays returns 86 matches ...

> I think there be six Richmonds in the field
>   King Richard III: V, iv

Comment: You mean the dragons aren't there anymore?

Comment: But even in Shakespeare, _be_ would not be used in a simple declarative sentence, "there be dragons there": it was subjunctive, and only used in a hypothetical or counterfactual way - here, because of "I think".

Comment: @ColinFine Would it not be perfectly normal for the chair of a meeting, in Britain, to say something like "If there be no further business, may I propose that we adjourn to the bar"? It is in everyday use.

Comment: @WS2: I would not regard it as the least bit normal. I would regard it as a bizarre bit of misapplied archaism.

Comment: @ColinFine  According to [NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=there+be&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthere%20be%3B%2Cc0) it remains alive and well in retirement - not what it once was, but still with us.

Comment: And what proportion of those are governed by a modal, @WS2? _Can/could/will/should/might there be_ are all current.

Comment: The iWeb corpus shows 50 719 instances of "[modal] there be" to 807 of "if there be".

Comment: And my comment about a **misapplied** archaism was because that is a _realis_ not an _irrealis_ context, so the subjunctive would not normally have been used there anyway.

Comment: @ColinFine - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_be_dragons